# I want know how to get $\sum_{m \gt 0, m\neq n } \frac{1}{m-n}- \frac{1}{m+n}=\frac{3}{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, summation-method

I am trying to understand this summation:
$$\sum_{m \gt 0, m\neq n} \frac{1}{m^2-n^2}=\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{m \gt 0, m\neq n } \left(\frac{1}{m-n}- \frac{1}{m+n}\right)=\frac{3}{4n^2}$$

But I can't see why the following step is right:
$$\sum_{m \gt 0, m\neq n } \left(\frac{1}{m-n}- \frac{1}{m+n}\right)=\frac{3}{2n}$$

Comment: I think my question is not clear to you. So I edited my question. I hope now my question is understandable.

Comment: I thought your original question was better, so I have restored it, with perhaps more transparent wording.

Comment: You have an interesting nickname! Is it a phonetic tribute to Euler? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $N>n$:

$$\sum_{m \gt 0, m\neq n, m\le N }\left( \frac{1}{m-n}- \frac{1}{m+n}\right)=[H_{N-n}-H_{n-1}]-[H_{N+n}-H_n-\frac{1}{2n}]$$

because:

$$\sum_{m \gt 0, m\neq n, m\le N }\left( \frac{1}{m-n}\right)=\frac{1}{1-n}+\frac{1}{2-n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{-1}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots\frac{1}{N-n}=-\left(\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n-2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots\frac{1}{N-n}\right)$$

$$\sum_{m \gt 0, m\neq n, m\le N } \left(\frac{1}{m+n}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n+N}\right)-\frac{1}{n+n}$$

Now, noting that $H_k=\log k +\gamma + o(1)$, we see that the sum up to $N$ will be

$$\log\left(\frac{N-n}{N+n}\right)+o(1)+H_n-H_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2n}$$

$$=\frac{3}{2n}+o(1)\to \frac{3}{2n}$$

(noting that $\log\left(\frac{N-n}{N+n}\right)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I want to know what is o(1). Usually $\lim_{k \to \infty} H_k-\log k=\gamma $?

Comment: Yep - $\lim_{k\to\infty}[H_k - \log k]=\gamma\iff H_k=\log k + \gamma + o(1)$. Just a notational thing - I generally find that o-notation can make things quite neat. $o(1)$ just means a term that goes to $0$ in the limit.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand that.